# C# Created DLL .NET 7, DllImport Don't work

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, dllexport, dllregistration

I don't understand why this error in my screen):

[image]

EdiUseDLL:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    const string Path = @"C:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\EdiUseDLL\EdiLibraryExample\bin\Release\net7.0\EdiLibraryExample.dll";
    [DllImport(Path, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int Add(int a, int b);

    static void Main()
    {
        int result = Add(5, 3);
        Console.WriteLine("Result of addition: " + result); 
    }
}
```

EdiLibraryExample:

```
namespace EdiLibraryExample
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

How to create dll which I can use with DLLImport in c#

I hope you will help me!)

Comment: Without "hacking" you can't ... (there are some solutions like [DllExport](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16310/How-to-Automate-Exporting-NET-Function-to-Unmanage) (I wrote it back in 2006 so it may not work) and similar)

Comment: you can just add dependency to this library and use `EdiLibraryExample.Class1.Add` directly ... there is no need for `DllImport` ... `DllImport` is for calling native libraries not .net assemblies

Comment: And how I can create dll in c# and use in c#? ) But I must use config file. In which will be set up path to dll. I can't add dll moment when I create project. I want add dll in moment when project exists in exe file with config file...

Comment: I only can use Assembly.LoadFrom?

Comment: Question, I can't use c# dll in others languages? c++, python, java?

Comment: To use a .Net assembly in a .Net assembly just reference the assembly. If you want o load it dynamically at runtime then you need Assembly.Load. And no, cross using things isn't typically easily possible by just importing/exporting stuff if the memory management  is different. And unmanged (like standard c++) is different from managed Net is different from managed Java.

Comment: Ok, question [DllImport] for what? If I can load dll with Assembly.Load?

Comment: Please reconsider using images in the Question. Text is searchable, and image links tend to die over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of DLLs: [managed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/managed-code) and unmanaged.

Managed refers to being managed by CLR. Typically DLLs compiled from C# are managed DLLs, which can be directly referenced by another C# project or dynamically loaded using methods such as `Assembly.LoadFrom`.

- Further reading: [Dependency loading in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/overview)

Other DLLs are called unmanaged DLLs, which are usually compiled from other programming languages such as C++. Using such DLLs in C# projects requires attributes such as `DllImportAttribute` to load them.

- Further reading: [Platform Invoke (P/Invoke)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke)

If a DLL is compiled from a C++/CLI project, it can contain both managed and unmanaged code.

Bottom line: you cannot use Assembly.LoadFrom for unmanaged DLLs.

Comment: There are four kinds of DLLs: resource-only (no managed code and no native code), pure managed (.NET metadata and MSIL code), native, and mixed-mode (containing both .NET metadata and native code, and usually also MSIL code).  Then the pure managed ones split further into architecture-agnostic aka AnyCPU and architecture-specific.  Native code is always architecture-specific.  All these details affect how to properly load and use the DLL.